# Redux Form: How to handle multiple buttons?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to add a second submit button to a [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form).

Both buttons should dispatch an action that saves the data but depending on the button pressed the user should be routed to different pages.

So I defined a handler that I pass as `onSubmit` prop to the form.

But as far as I can see only the form **data** is passed to this handler:

The docs on [`handleSubmit`](http://redux-form.com/5.2.3/#/api/props?_k=dba65a) note:

> A function meant to be passed to `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`
>   or to `<button onClick={handleSubmit}>`.
>   It will run validation, both sync and async, and, if the form is valid,
>   it will call `this.props.onSubmit(data)` with the contents of the form data.

What I am missing is a way to also pass the information about the button pressed (e.g. the click event) to my onSubmit handler, so that i can save and route as intended.

Comment: I have a similar issue but instead of redirecting to different pages, I need to trigger the validations dynamically based on the button clicked.

What i want is that on click of any button, a flag is set (ex. `isSaveMode = true`) and on the basis of this flag, I need to trigger validations on specific fields like so:

`<Field {...props} validate={isSaveMode && [validateRequiredText]}/>`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but they all involve appending the button data depending on which button was pressed. Here's an inline version.

```
class Morpheus extends Component {
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        Fields go here
        <button onClick={handleSubmit(values => 
          this.props.onSubmit({ 
            ...values,
            pill: 'blue'
          }))}>Blue Pill</button>
        <button onClick={handleSubmit(values => 
          this.props.onSubmit({ 
            ...values,
            pill: 'red'
          }))}>Red Pill</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'morpheus'
})(Morpheus)
```

The `handleSubmit` handles all the validation checking and whatnot, and if everything is valid, it will call the function given to it with the form values. So we give it a function that appends extra information and calls `onSubmit()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was a bit confused by the the interplay between the different props and handlers but your solution makes totally sense.

Comment: Hey Erik, first of all thank you for the `redux-form` :). Secondly, it do working but it feels a little hacky, like a hidden value field. For example I working on a generic form and maybe somebody will use a property named `pill`. I really would like to bind the function somehow and pass it as another argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, because onSubmit is required for the <Form>, you cannot wrap your form with <Form> (and therefore lose usability features). Any way to do so without needing to remove the <form>?

Comment: Ahhh, took a minute longer to think it through: just keep the form with the default action and then for any additional buttons add the delineating value accordingly.

Comment: where is this.props.onSubmit coming from?

Comment: @mibbit the redux-form higher order component provides it

Comment: Please also note that this will not work if your `onSubmit` function returns a promise, in which case you will need to wait for it to resolve first: `button onClick={handleSubmit(values).then( /*...*/ )}`

Comment: I have a similar issue but instead of redirecting to different pages, I need to trigger the validations dynamically based on the button clicked. What i want is that on click of any button, a flag is set (ex. `isSaveMode = true`) and on the basis of this flag, I need to trigger validations on specific fields like so:                  `<Field {...props} validate={isSaveMode && [validateRequiredText]}/>`

Answer (score 2):

@mibbit onSubmit is a function that you define (at least this is what the doc says: [look the onSubmit method](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/)). This is for redux-form 7.x following example of @Erik R.

```
    class Morpheus extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(values, pill) {
        // do magic here
    }

    render() {
        const {
            handleSubmit
        } = this.props;
        return ( <
            div >
            Fields go here <
            button onClick = {
                handleSubmit(values =>
                    this.onSubmit({
                        values,
                        pill: 'blue'
                    }))
            } > Blue Pill < /button> <
            button onClick = {
                handleSubmit(values =>
                    this.onSubmit({
                        values,
                        pill: 'red'
                    }))
            } > Red Pill < /button> <
            /div>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'morpheus'
})(Morpheus)
```