# redux-form [v6] Form with multiple submit buttons, detecting which button

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

At the moment I am attaching a handler to each submit button so that I can know in the submit handler which one triggered the submit, using setState() to just track at component level only which button was pressed.

In my Component that renders the form and handles submit.

```
flagButtonComplete = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({ flagComplete: true });
}
```

Which is then passed down through a few sub components to the submit buttons that need to be complete button rather than a save button.

Then in my submit

```
submit = (values: any) => {
    const saveAction = this.state.flagComplete
        ? this.props.saveComplete(values)
        : this.props.save(values);
```

Just wondering if there might be some other way to detect which button as I have to thread this submit button clicked handler down through 2 layers of components.

Might there be some way I have missed to get the values object as given to submit via some other api possibly ?

Comment: have a click handler for the buttons, instead of submit handler for the form?

Comment: @Vijay thats the last question in the post... I cant see how to get the redux-form 'values' object any other place than via the submit handler API in redux-form v6 (currently rc.3) at the moment.

Comment: You could try something like this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37173842/103690)?

Comment: Thanks, I stumbled on to that a while back(month or two). I havn't had a chance to get back to my project since I asked this though. At the time I asked the question it wasn't clear to me from documentation on how to extend the set of submitted values.