# redux reading a value from <input type=text>

Tags: redux, textfield

I am writing a simple redux app and one of the components looks like this

```
const LoginComponent = ({onLoginClick, onRegisterClick}) => (
    <div className={styles.loginDiv}>
        <p className={standardStyles.pageTitleText}>SyncSpace</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <div className={styles.loginRegisterDiv}>
            <button className={styles.loginButton} onClick={onLoginClick}>Login</button>
            <button className={styles.registerButton} onClick={onRegisterClick}>Register</button>
        </div>

    </div>
);
```

On the click events I want to read the values typed into the username and password fields and pass them as parameters to the onLoginClick event.  What is the proper way to read this value in Redux?

Answer (score 4):

Redux-Form is overkill.  You **definitely** don't need any kind of library to read from forms.

This is actually not a Redux question, specifically - it's a React question.  There's two ways to handle form values in React: "controlled" inputs, and "uncontrolled" inputs.  When you ask "how can I read the values on click", the answer is "read them from the inputs themselves using refs" for uncontrolled inputs, and "read the values from your component's state" for controlled inputs.

Gosha Arinich has several articles that explain the basics of how to use forms in React, and I highly recommend you read through those first: https://goshakkk.name/on-forms-react/ .  They explain the ideas of "controlled" and "uncontrolled" inputs, and how to use them.  (Gosha also just released an excellent book on forms and React, which I also recommend.  It goes into greater detail than the blog posts: https://goshakkk.name/the-missing-forms-handbook-of-react/ ).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at **[redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form)**.

It is a very active project with a great community to answer any questions.

Here is an example of how to [attach a form to the redux store](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/simple/).

Using redux-form, you can change your form to something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const LoginComponent = ({onRegisterClick, onLoginClick}) => (
  <form onSubmit={onRegisterClick} className={styles.loginDiv}>
      <p className={standardStyles.pageTitleText}>SyncSpace</p>
      <Field name="userName" component="input" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
      <Field name="password" component="input" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      <div className={styles.loginRegisterDiv}>
        <button type="submit" className={styles.loginButton}>Login</button>
      </div>
  </form>
);
```

I personally prefer to have the registration and login actions happen on two separate views, but if you do choose to have two buttons in your redux-form, there are multiple ways to do so. [This is a good answer on attaching the action to the onClick handlers as you do, but a modification to the action so that it takes in a parameter.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37173842/4976648)